# What do we say when we want to tell someone to stand with his back touching the wall?

Tags: prepositions

Which sentence is correct to use: **Stand against the wall** or **Stand with the wall**?

Comment: Hi aimi! We say. 'Stand against the wall' or 'Stand with your back to wall'. '*Backs* to the wall' can be used on its own if there's more than one person, but '*Back* to the wall' is ambiguous. sounding like 'Go back to the wall' - as if s/he recently *left* the wall.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question and appropriate for the group.  Not sure why it was down voted.

Comment: Lean to the wall - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lean

Comment: @RamPillai "Lean to the wall" doesn't sound idiomatic. "To" would suggest "toward" and is not the same thing as "lean **against** the wall". "Lean towards the wall" sounds much better but is still not the answer. "**Against**" is what the OP is looking for here.

Comment: @RamPillai interesting, where is "lean to" used like that? Where I'm from we could say "lean against the wall", but I never recall hearing "lean to the wall" (though we have the noun "lean-to" which appears to come from your usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say "stand against the wall."